# Bootstrap modal doesn't scroll after child modal closed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3 I have a modal form (let's call it the parent modal). It is called like this:

`<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#receiptmodal" data-backdrop="static"  data-keyboard="false">
<i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
<strong>Receive Money</strong>
</a>`

It has child modals called like this:

`$('#childmodal').modal({backdrop: "static", keyboard: "false"});`

The parent is taller than my view port and it does scroll, but after the child modal is closed, the parent won't scroll - instead, the page holding the parent modal scrolls even though it is still greyed out and disabled.

The child modal is closed like this:
`$("#childmodal").modal('hide');`. I've also tried `toggle` with no luck.

Why is this happening? I need the parent modal to scroll like it does before opening and closing child modals.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the DOM after the modal closed, the body still had this class applied: ".modal-open".

Removal of this class would bring the page back to normal conditions, the scroll and so. So you need to:

```
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that insight. With that, I saw that closing the child modal removed that class, so putting back made my parent scroll again!! So I've just added $('body').addClass('modal-open'); after closing the children.

Comment: Great, I had faced similar problem before.

Comment: Sorry dear, not worked for me. But another solution worked $('#booknowmodel').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        // do something…
        $('body').addClass('modal-open');
    });

Answer (score 4):

Although joashp helped me find the answer, I wanted to post an answer for completeness.

Joashp is correct about the `modal-open` class in the body and my testing showed that adding that class allowed the parent modal to scroll again. The problem is that whilst it worked in testing, it didn't in the real world. To fix the problem completely, I add to add the `modal-open` class to the body AFTER jQuery finished hiding the modal completely. To do that, I had to use the callback for the modal. "hidden" fires when jQuery is finally finished hiding:

`$('#childmodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('body').addClass('modal-open');
    });`

Answer (score 2):

The true answer is in the timing. After spending a few hours tracing through what was happening to the classes, I tried the following and it just works like it should. Basically, you need to wait for the initial modal to completely hide BEFORE you attempt to open the second modal. Like this.

```
$("#idmodal1").modal("hide");
/*When the modal is COMPLETELY hidden */
$("#idmodal1").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                        $("#idmodal2").modal("show");/*Show the second modal*/ 
                   });
```

The second modal will now scroll as normal.